# Core Data, Dictionary or plist?

Tags: iphone, core-data, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I wanted to get some advice as to which direction would suit the app I am trying to create. Basically, I am creating a sort of "diary" app that would allow people to track weight/diet changes and offer tips and advice as the app detects certain kinds of fluctuations.

I need to be able to save these weight/diet changes as the user adds them (so I don't want to overwrite the data I'm storing). I also need to be able to add multiple users.

Having said all that, I have been researching all of the ways to store persistent data in OBJC and see that it looks to be a choice between Core Data, using a Mutable Dictionary or possibly a plist file. Given my needs above, can anyone provide some guidance?

I am extremely new to Objective-C (and programming in general). I have been wanting to build my own app for a long time and decided to pull the trigger and go for it. I've purchased several books on it and have done a tonne of tutorials (written and video) - reviewed Apple's own documentation. I have basically been trying to find a tutorial close to what I am needing to do, but am running into issues with that. Any help and advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you new, start with pList, here is a decent tutorial for plist http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFqqaN5gGzc for core data, this is the best tutorial I have found http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G36_91H4CKE

Comment: Thank you Smick... I am watching the CD tut now... that helps a lot, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For persistent data, you can go with CoreData / SQLite / Plist.

`NSDictionary` is not a thing which stores data in harddisk. It is only a data-structure that help you to manage the data and in the end you need to write the values to the disk.

If your database size is not big and very basic things like key-value pair (personName with weight and diet) plist will suffice.

If you need to do searching / sorting / query then coredata / sqlite will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you Anoop! That is really helpful to know about NSDictionary. I think I might go the CoreData route as I am planning on implementing a photograph along with the name,age,weight data... It sounds like plist isn't capable of that...

Comment: You can save images to plist, but for this you need to archive it.